# Port forwarding through a client bridge

Tags: router, port-forwarding, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge

I am having a problem with port forwarding with a client bridge. My main router is a 2wire router from AT&T using their firmware. It is a Router/Modem.

In my room, there is a Linksys WRT54GL with DD-WRT on it. I have set up the DD-WRT one as a Client bridge for my PC. I can access the internet on my computer using it but when I try and port forward, the ports stay closed. I am port forwarding on my main router (2wire) and it doesn't work. I have checked online and all I see is that I should only need to forward on the main router since the client bridge has NAT disabled, but it seems to not work that way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem w/ the same setup, but think I solved it by configuring the main  router (2wire) to forward the port to the client-bridge w/ dd-wrt instead of the computer name. Please note this 2wire router forwards based on name and not IP address.

After some trial & error I reconfigured the 2wire router/gateway by navigating to Settings>Firewall>Applications,Pinholes, & DMZ once in this window I created a new user-defined application w/ any name of your choosing and w/ the corresponding TCP port, added it to the list and clicked 'back.'

Here's the defining moment, for the field 'select a computer' the name of your client-bridged router w/ the dd-wrt should appear on the list.

Select it, choose 'allow individual application', choose 'user defined', in the list on the left choose the entry you created and then click 'Add', Once you are all done click 'Save', and your all done. Hope this helps someone.

*ref. for configuring your 2wire gateway* - http://www.pcwintech.com/port-forwarding-2wire-routersmodems

Comment: You will need to clear dervices and restart ATT router.  It has caching issues.